# Oracle SQL Developer multiple table views

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In **Oracle SQL Developer**, one can list the data in a table using the Data tab when viewing a table. there where can add, delete, edit or just viewing records of table currently viewd

the problem is that we often really need to view more than one table at once, then we need more than one tab opened, thing that i dont know how to do that, any sugestion. tq in advance

Answer (score 350):

SQL Developer can start a new tab every time you select a database object to view; but, you will have to close the tab manually.

Set this in:
*Tools->Preferences->Database->ObjectViewer->Automatically Freeze Object Viewer Windows*

Answer (score 293):

You can pin a tab by clicking the button below :

### [image: Tab pin button]

No need to configure anything, plus sometimes you don't want to have a tab automatically pinned.

Answer (score 8):

Jeff Smith posted a nice write up on how to do this in SQL Developer.

There are multiple ways to do it.

- Freeze content (ctrl-shift-P)
- New Document Tab Group (will allow viewing tables simultaneously)
- Change the preferences (If this is desired default behavior)

The post can be found [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/05/how-to-see-two-tables-at-the-same-time-in-oracle-sql-developer/).